# Calling CreateFile with \\?\ prefixing the pathname fails (but the directory structure exists

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

```
TCHAR szPathName[MAX_PATH*2]={0};
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile( szPathName, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, NULL );
```

after the call, `hFile` is `-1` and `GetLastError() == 123`;

if the following path is used `"\\?\C:\\Temp\\Today\\NewDir\\SubDir\\my_new_file.dat"` where `SubDir` exists, it fails.  I read that `\\?\` is used when a path is bigger than `MAX_PATH`.

Comment: \ is supposed to be doubled.

Comment: `L"\\\\?\\C:\\Temp\\Today\\NewDir\\SubDir\\my_new_file.dat"` must be (only unicode)

Comment: `R"aw("\\?\C:\Temp\Today\NewDir\SubDir\my_new_file.dat)aw";` - Use raw string literals when you have to mix in a lot of backslashes (add `L` for wide chars)

Comment: @TedLyngmo This is good. But isn't there an additional `"`? Should start with ```R"aw(\\``` I think.

Comment: @Afshin `R"aw(\\?\C:\Temp\Today\NewDir\SubDir\my_new_file.dat)aw";` - Indeed - I missed that one.

Comment: Is there any advantage of `R"aw(...)` over `R"(...)` ? I've never heard anything about `R"aw(...)` !